# Not able to append to existing file to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I have single node Hadoop 1.2.1 cluster running on VM.

My hdfs-site.xml looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
 </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.support.append</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Does HDFS allow appends to files?
  </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Now when I'm trying to run the following code from Eclipse it returns me always false:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.set("mapred.job.tracker","10.0.0.6:54311");
    config.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://10.0.0.6:54310");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);
    boolean flag = Boolean.getBoolean(fs.getConf().get("dfs.support.append"));
    System.out.println("dfs.support.append is set to be " + flag);
```

Now If I'm trying to append to existing file I'll get the following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: Append is not supported. Please see the dfs.support.append configuration parameter
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:1781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.append(NameNode.java:725)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.append(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.append(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.append(DFSClient.java:933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.append(DFSClient.java:922)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.append(DistributedFileSystem.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.append(FileSystem.java:659)
    at com.vanilla.hadoop.AppendToHdfsFile.main(AppendToHdfsFile.java:29)
```

What is wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try with a 2.X.X version or 0.2X version because appending a file on hdfs after hadoop 0.20.2. See more information at [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/01/an-update-on-apache-hadoop-1-0/) and [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/07/file-appends-in-hdfs/)

Answer (score 1):

Append is not supported since 1.0.3. Anyway, if you really need the previous functionality, to turn on the append functionality set the flag "dfs.support.broken.append" to true.

[hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/releasenotes.html](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/releasenotes.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Let's now start with configuring the file system:**

```
public FileSystem configureFileSystem(String coreSitePath, String hdfsSitePath) {
    FileSystem fileSystem = null;
    try {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.setBoolean("dfs.support.append", true);
        Path coreSite = new Path(coreSitePath);
        Path hdfsSite = new Path(hdfsSitePath);
        conf.addResource(coreSite);
        conf.addResource(hdfsSite);
        fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error occurred while configuring FileSystem");
    }
    return fileSystem;
}
```

Make sure that the property dfs.support.append in hdfs-site.xml is set to true.

You can either set it manually by editing the hdfs-site.xml file or programmatically using:

**conf.setBoolean("dfs.support.append", true);**

**Let's start with appending to a file in HDFS.**

```
public String appendToFile(FileSystem fileSystem, String content, String dest) throws IOException {
    Path destPath = new Path(dest);
    if (!fileSystem.exists(destPath)) {
        System.err.println("File doesn't exist");
        return "Failure";
    }
    Boolean isAppendable = Boolean.valueOf(fileSystem.getConf().get("dfs.support.append"));
    if(isAppendable) {
        FSDataOutputStream fs_append = fileSystem.append(destPath);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fs_append);
        writer.append(content);
        writer.flush();
        fs_append.hflush();
        writer.close();
        fs_append.close();
        return "Success";
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Please set the dfs.support.append property to true");
        return "Failure";
    }
}
```

To see whether the data has been correctly written to HDFS, let's write a method to read from HDFS and return the content as a String.

```
public String readFromHdfs(FileSystem fileSystem, String hdfsFilePath) {
    Path hdfsPath = new Path(hdfsFilePath);
    StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder("");
    try{
        BufferedReader bfr=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileSystem.open(hdfsPath)));
        String str;
        while ((str = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
            fileContent.append(str+"\n");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("----------Could not read from HDFS---------\n");
    }
    return fileContent.toString();
}
```

After that, we have successfully written and read the file in HDFS. It's time to close the file system.

```
public void closeFileSystem(FileSystem fileSystem){
    try {
        fileSystem.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("----------Could not close the FileSystem----------");
    }
}
```

Before executing the code, you should have Hadoop running on your system.

You just need to go to HADOOP_HOME and run following command:

**./sbin/start-all.sh**

For Complete Reference use https://github.com/ksimar/HDFS_AppendAPI